# How to have a global alias for network requests in Cypress

Tags: cypress

In my e2e tests it happens that I have to wait for a xhr request to finish. So I have created an alias "graphql":

```
cy.server();
cy.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: Cypress.env('GRAPHQL_API'),
}).as("graphql");
```

It just listens to all POST requests, which is fine. I use it like this:

```
cy.wait("@graphql");
```

The problem is, I need to redeclare this alias not only in every test file but also in every single test! There must be a way to globally define this alias but I cannot find it.

Comment: Have you tried using it inside a before all hook?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using it in a hook:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  cy.server();
cy.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: Cypress.env('GRAPHQL_API'),
}).as("graphql");
})

it('test', function () {
  cy.wait("@graphql");
})
```

Note that, alias works only with beforeEach and not before all, as alias will be cleared after each spec (means each 'it' block) .

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/665

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to have a global alias for network requests; **[cy.server](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Notes)** only persists until the next test.

Depending on how your application behavior, you can create an helper function in your index.js and then call it for each needed test.

```
export const globalXHRpost = () => {
    cy.server()
    cy.route({
       method: "POST",
       url: Cypress.env('GRAPHQL_API')
       })
      .as("graphql")
    cy.visit('URL') //or whichever action initiates XHR
    cy.wait("@graphql")
}
```

You might consider restructuring your tests to have the alias cover XHR more than once.